# Function executed even if it belongs to a different build variant?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My setup:

- buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0

Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

    // ...

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile getReleaseKeyStoreFile()
     // ...    

     File getReleaseKeyStoreFile() {
         String keyStoreFile = System.getenv("KEYSTORE_FILE")
         if (keyStoreFile == null || keyStoreFile == "") {
             println 'ERROR: Failed getting release keyStoreFile'
             return null
     }
     return file(keyStoreFile)
}
```

When I run the gradle task `assembleDebug` I'm getting this in the Gradle build messages:

`Failed getting releaseKeyStoreFile`

1. Why is this function evaluated even though the build variant is `debug` and not `release`?
2. Is there a simple work-around to avoid this unwanted behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the *configuration phase* and the *execution phase*.

In the *configuration phase*, the whole build script is evaluated and executed.
Only task actions (defined by task types), `doFirst` and `doLast` closures are executed in the *execution phase*.

Whether a task is executed (explicit or as dependency) only affects the *execution phase*, but nevertheless it will always be configured.

You can call each task, the configuration code in your `android` closure will **always** be executed.

To answer your second question: Your method must be fail-safe (as it is right now). There is no problem in returning  `null` to the `storeFile` property, since only the task (which is not executed) will fail.

An additional hint: You can simplify your method. There is no need to check for `null` **and** an empty string, you can simply check for Groovy truth. You can use a ternary expression, too.

```
return keyStoreFile ? file(keyStoreFile) : null
```